# Convert Integer to binary and array and compare rows with the array and select where array value is 1

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have this function in DatabaseSQLite.java (Android App) that I pass a 'id' and it return for my the Data with this id.

```
public Cursor getData(Integer id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL1 +" = " + id;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

And this is my SQLite table with 15 rows:

[image]

For example, if I pass '12' for this function, it will return the row 12.

But my doubt is how can I convert this Integer id to a binary and then to a array and compare this array with the rows of the TABLE_NAME, and select just the rows with the array value 1.

For example, here I convert this 4 numbers to binary to give you 4 examples:

[image]

Then I will have this 4 arrays ( the background blue is that have the 1 value)

[image]

So, if a pass 1, 5, 59 or 32767 or any other number for my function, I'd like this respective result for each example 1, 5, 59 and 32767:

[image]

Anyone have ideia of how can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `id` to a binary string and call the `getData` with argument index + `1` for each index where the value is `1`. this will fetch all the rows one by one.

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(id);

for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
    if(binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
        Cursor data = getData(i+1); // get (i+1)th row
        // do something
    }
}
```

Also, you can modify `getdata` to select all rows at once

```
public Cursor getData(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(id);

    // buliding query SELCT * FROM TABLE WHERE id in (id1, id2, id3, id4 ...)
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL1 + "in (";
    boolean isFirst = true; // to avoid appending ',' before first id

    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        if(binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            if(!isFirst) {
                query += ", ";
                isFirst = false;
            }
            query += (i+1);
        }
    }
    query += ")";

    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I would like to call the function "public Cursor getData(Integer id)"  and it return the doubt in this question (i need this function just for it),So I need to modify this function with your sugestion, how it will be? I tried here, but it didn't work.

Comment: I tested the conversion of interger to binary and it works, now I need to compare this binary string to my rows of table like the examples in pictures. where will be my select statement here: `for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
    if(binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
        Cursor data = getData(i+1); // get (i+1)th row
        // do something
    }
}`

Comment: SELECT statement will be in your `getdata` method.. which is called inside the loop.